# AngularJS: Not able to get $scope value jquery tabs, but outside I am getting the value

Tags: angularjs

I am using [jQuery Tabs](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic), but unable to get the $scope variable data inside the tabs. Here is the code from view:

```
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1" id="myTabDrop1-contents">
     <li ng-repeat="event_name in myEvents">
         <a ng-click="selectedEventDetail(event_name._id)" href="#dropdownEventDetail" role="tab" id="dropdownEventDetail-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="dropdownm" aria-expanded="true">{{event_name.name}}</a>
     </li>
     <li class=""><a href="#createNewEvent" role="tab" id="createNewEvent-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="dropdowns" aria-expanded="false">Create New</a></li>
     </ul>
<!-- Tab Content -->
     <div class="tab-content">
                  HTML {{singleEvent}}    //prints data over here
                  <!-- Dynamic Event Detail Section starts here -->
<div class="tab-pane fade in" role="tabpanel" id="dropdownEventDetail" aria-labelledby="dropdownEventDetail-tab">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="EventDetail-Wizard">
    <h3>Keyboard</h3>
    <section> 
        {{$parent.singleEvent}} val {{singleEvent}}  // does not print 
    </section>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div></div>
```

Here is the code from controller:

```
$scope.selectedEventDetail = function(event_id){
        Events.findById({'_id':event_id}).then(function(response){
            console.log(response) // returns object
            $scope.singleEvent=response.data // returns object
        })
    }
```

How I can use my $scope variable data inside the tab?

Comment: This won't work.  You should not use plugins from jQuery such as jQuery-Tabs, because they change the DOM but don't tell AngularJs that the changes were made, and this causes the 2 way binding to break.  There are ways to trick AngularJs or force an update, but in general you should use AngularJs compliant methods and not use plugins that modify the DOM directly.

Comment: Claies is right. Using jQuery along with AngularJS is a bad choice. How about something like https://github.com/angular-wizard/angular-wizard

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. DOM that includes interpolation `{{ }}` binding needs to be compiled with the `$compile` service. The jQuery tabs plugin adds template to the DOM without compiling it. Instead use the [AngularUI uib-tabs library](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!tabs).

Comment: Another library to consider is [ng-bootstrap tabs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/examples).